# Unique font for the whole tikz graphic

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fonts

With the tikzpicture environment, I want to have a single font (helvetica) for all the elements of the graphic. On the sample code given below, only the legend and the axis labels take the helvetica font.

Thank you in advance for your interest in my request.

**Code sample**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,final,french]{book}

\headheight = 15pt 
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, left=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{helvet} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{Noir50}{RGB}{50, 50, 50}
\definecolor{Noir100}{RGB}{100, 100, 100}
\definecolor{Noir150}{RGB}{150, 150, 150}
\definecolor{Noir200}{RGB}{200, 200, 200}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[ height=6cm, width=0.7\textwidth, axis lines=left,ymin=-3500, ymax=3500,xmin=-6, xmax=6, xlabel={Label 1},ylabel={Label 2}] 
            \addplot[smooth,mark=square,Noir50] {-x^5 - 242}; 
            \addlegendentry{model} 
            \addplot[smooth,mark=*,Noir100] coordinates { 
            (-4.77778,2027.60977) (-3.55556,347.84069) (-2.33333,22.58953) (-1.11111,-493.50066) (0.11111,46.66082) (1.33333,-205.56286) (2.55556,-341.40638) (3.77778,-1169.24780) (5.00000,-3269.56775) }; \addlegendentry{estimate} 
        \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Example of curve}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Rendering of the sample**
[image]

Comment: The axis labels use the math font, and `\usepackage{helvet}` provides only a text font probably. You could try `\usepackage{mathastext}`. However, this also changes other math. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423137/disabling-mathastext-in-middle-of-the-document for more information.

Comment: Related questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpgfplots%5D+tick+label+font

Answer (score 2):

Tick labels are typeset in math mode by default, see the doc for option `/pgfplots/xticklabel={<command>}` in `pgfplots` manual.

To set helvetica also as math font, see [Math font Helvetica non-italic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328693/math-font-helvetica-non-italic). Note this normally has a global effect. Also check the related questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpgfplots%5D+tick+label+font.

To typeset tick labels in text mode, try

```tex
xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}},
/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true
```

Full example

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,final,french]{book}

\headheight = 15pt 
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, left=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{helvet} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{Noir50}{RGB}{50, 50, 50}
\definecolor{Noir100}{RGB}{100, 100, 100}
\definecolor{Noir150}{RGB}{150, 150, 150}
\definecolor{Noir200}{RGB}{200, 200, 200}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \pgfset{}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[ height=6cm, width=0.7\textwidth, axis lines=left,ymin=-3500, ymax=3500,xmin=-6, xmax=6, xlabel={Label 1},ylabel={Label 2},
        xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}},
        /pgf/number format/assume math mode=true
        ] 
            \addplot[smooth,mark=square,Noir50] {-x^5 - 242}; 
            \addlegendentry{model} 
            \addplot[smooth,mark=*,Noir100] coordinates { 
            (-4.77778,2027.60977) (-3.55556,347.84069) (-2.33333,22.58953) (-1.11111,-493.50066) (0.11111,46.66082) (1.33333,-205.56286) (2.55556,-341.40638) (3.77778,-1169.24780) (5.00000,-3269.56775) }; \addlegendentry{estimate} 
        \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Example of curve}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @muzimuzhiZ. I am well served. Have a good day !